# Opening a flash file on a different form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, flash, axshockwaveflash

Ok so I made two programs. 
Program one opens a flash file in a different from after a user clicks on a listview item.
Program two i made after program one didnt work. program two does the same thing except the user clicks on a button.
Now the confusing thing is that i used the same code for both programs BUT my program two works and my program one does not. any advice? here is the coding for both.
this is program two.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Debugger.IsAttached Then
        AbsoluteRef = Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\Resources\")
    Else
        AbsoluteRef = Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mefind = AbsoluteRef & shockfile & "ms access 4.swf"

    Form1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

and in my module i declared mefind and shockfile as string with the exception that shockfile is equal to the string "\Flash\"

and program one

```
Private Sub LvVideo_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LvVideo.DoubleClick
    If LvVideo.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Select Case LvVideo.SelectedItems(0).Text
            Case "MS Access 1"
                FlashVideos = AbsoluteRef & shockfile & "msaccessc1_demo1.swf"
                frmVideos.ShowDialog()
            Case "MS Access 2"
                FlashVideos = AbsoluteRef & shockfile & "msaccessc2_demo1.swf"
                frmVideos.ShowDialog()
            Case "MS Access 3"
                FlashVideos = AbsoluteRef & shockfile & "msaccessc3_demo1.swf"
                frmVideos.ShowDialog()
            Case "MS Access 4"
                FlashVideos = AbsoluteRef & shockfile & "ms access 4.swf"
                frmVideos.ShowDialog()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

But like I said one side works one does not i have tried numerous things such as closing vs and adding a different shockwave object to well creating a new program to just try and figure out what is going on. What i am really confused about is my second application working and my first one not

Comment: Do you also use `Debugger.IsAttached` in program One?

Comment: Yes the coding for both is pretty much the same

Comment: Just for the debugging, can you write `msgbox(AbsoluteRef & shockfile & "ms access 4.swf")` inside `button1_click` and `LvVideo_DoubleClick` and tell us the difference of the messages?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the path i have pause the debugging before at the point where it should be showing me my form and it showed the path as it should have been in fact the flash file opened in the flash player installed on the pc i am working on

Comment: Try to initialize the shockwave control to an absolute file path(manually written by you using a string) in the frmVideos form load event. If it work, then the value of the variable FlashVideos  above is either incorrect or have been changed just before its value is assigned to the shockwave control

Comment: I found a solution though i had recently upgraded my adobe so it actually messed somethings up on three of the programs that i am working on including this so i just removed the control from com reference and added into the source code again.
I had thought of that but the problem them is that the application needs to be installed on different computers which is why i dont use constant file paths.